# Ubuntu 16: pip install installs to python 3 instead of 2

Tags: 16.04, python, pip

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. I know it came with only python 3 installed, but somehow python 2 got in there ( I guess as a dependency). That's ok because i would add it anyway. Both python versions are present as can be seen with:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.11+
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.1+
```

My problem is that pip and pip3 both default to python3 (and there's no pip2 either). For example:

```
$ sudo -H pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
$ sudo -H pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

For what it's worth they are referring to different fodlers:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

How do I make pip install to python2 and pip3 install to python3 like in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has Python 2 and 3 in the installation. It's just that as of now, everything from Ubuntu is supposed to use Python 3 instead of 2. And anything in `/usr/local` is not from Ubuntu. It's installed by you, probably by compiling Python from source.

Comment: It's not compiled from source - haven't learnt how to do that. In any case what do i need to fix to add packages to python 2 as well?

Comment: Ty running `/usr/bin/pip`. Ubuntu's `pip` is still for Python 2.

Comment: ll | grep pip in /usr/bin shows only pip3 results for some reason !?

Comment: Then install it: `sudo apt-get install python-pip`.

Comment: hm! maybe I did things wrong. since what I posted still kept pip from showing up there I did what you said. Now pip is there. I need to check for potential conflicts now I m afraid.

Comment: By the way muru your comments are far better solution. If you want to write and answer saying check /user/bin and then install I ll accept it.

Comment: ah, no, thanks. I tend to steer clear of Python problems involving `/usr/local`. It's far more trouble than whatever the user thought it is worth. You'll probably run it more problems down the line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40627/discussion-between-karsus-and-muru).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works, and hopefully I didn't break anything in the process. At first I tried editing the first line in /usr/local/bin/pip to change it from python 3 to python 2 compiler but got error that there was no module named pip !?

So I thought maybe I need install it for python 2. So I went [there](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and saved the get-pip.py script they offered. There is a warning that it might break stuff for the OS but since xenial uses only python3 I decided to risk it. And it worked:

```
$ sudo -H pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
$ sudo -H pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

There is still the potential problem that stuff are in /usr/local that muru mentioned but I don't know much about it and if stuff keep working I will not complain. The only ways I ve added packages are apt-get and some .deb files in rare exceptions (like chrome iirc).

Comment: I think the reason numpy is in /usr/local is that I installed it through pip and not through apt. Just mentioning it here in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

after installing both

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

under Ubuntu 16.04 I can simply use

```
pip2 install module
pip3 install module
```

to install the desired module for Python2 or Python3, respectively.

I hope that is helpful and works for you, too!

Answer (score 2):

Face same issue solved by unlinking pip from python3 by reinstalling it as following:

```
sudo python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but since none of the answers fixed the issue for me and I could not find any other solution online I thought I would share what finally worked for me.

Running these two lines corrected the problem for me and now pip installs modules for python2

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

python get-pip.py
```