# Installing pip3

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, python, python3

I had followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/879034/484475) to install pip3; I need it to install other python3 packages. I don't remember if I installed pip3 a long time before. After running `sudo apt install python3-pip`, I get the following as the output,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libuv1-dev
  linux-headers-4.13.0-37 linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-38 linux-headers-4.13.0-38-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-39 linux-headers-4.13.0-39-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-41 linux-headers-4.13.0-41-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-43 linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-45 linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-39-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-38-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-39-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-41-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-45-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 236 not upgraded.
```

However, When I type `which pip3`, I do not get any output. Again, When I typed `pip3 -V`, I get the following response:

```
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I tried `dpkg -L python3-pip` and got the following as the output:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/not-zip-safe
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/entry_points.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/baseparser.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_file.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/status_codes.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/setuptools_build.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/appdirs.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/logging.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/encoding.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/deprecation.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/filesystem.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/build.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat/dictconfig.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat/ordereddict.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models/index.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/bazaar.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/git.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/cmdoptions.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/completion.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/hash.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/show.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/download.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/wheel.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/help.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/pep425tags.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip/copyright
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/pip3
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip/changelog.Debian.gz
```

which implies that pip3 has been installed.

How do I resolve this issue?

**Some more details:** I have python 2.7 and python 3 installed in /usr/local/lib/. The python 2.7 has the following pip installations:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-10.0.0.dist-info
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.0.dist-info
```

while there is no pip3 installation in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/. There is only a pip installation in python3.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `/home/shuba/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/shuba/bin:/home/shuba/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin`

Comment: Everything seems okay in your PATH, what happens if you run pip like this: `/usr/bin/pip3 -V` ?

Comment: I get this: 

`/usr/bin/pip3 -V
bash: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory`

Comment: run: `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip` it might help.

Comment: After running it, I get the output for `which pip3` as `usr/bin/pip3`

However, if I type `pip3 -v`, I get this: [link] (https://pastebin.com/kbUECtCF)

Comment: How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what can be the cause of issue at all. but try installing: `sudo apt install python3-dev`

Comment: I got the following output: https://pastebin.com/RyyDy4r4

Answer (score 1):

Try `python3 -m pip3 install pip`.

You may be trying to use Python2 to run pip3 and that's why you're seeing the error.